# React-Native: Accessing methods in file included using require()

Tags: javascript, react-native

When splitting methods into seperate class files in react native how do I then access those classes from another file?

For example in included.js I have the following:

```
'use strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native';

var myClass = React.createClass({

    doStuff: function(){
        return 'Hello';
    },

    render: function(){ //This is required???

    },

})

module.exports = myClass;
```

In my index.ios.js file I have:

`var myClass = require('./included');`

How do I now call a function from myClass?

I'm new to using react native and suspect my current approach is not ideal but haven't found a clear example of how to seperate my code.  For example external API calling methods in a class from the classes that build the views in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just simply call a method in another component. React has its own design pattern and it does not allow that. 
Accodring to React [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html):

> For communication between two components that don't have a
>   parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event
>   system. Subscribe to events in componentDidMount(), unsubscribe in
>   componentWillUnmount(), and call setState() when you receive an event.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll rethink my design.